# Como inserir atributos async e defer sem o valor com CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou utilizando o Framework PHP CakePHP 3.0.3 e gostaria de saber como faço para inserir as palavras chave **defer** e **async** nas tags de script e omitir os valores:

Como é feita a inserção de script com o framework:

```
<?= $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.1.min.js') ?>
```

Como é renderizado:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Como como gostaria que fosse:

```
<script async src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Na documentação não vi nada que pude-se fazer esta inserção.

Uma forma alternativa que estou utilizando é fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?= $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.1.min.js',['defer' => true]) ?>
```

e esta renderizando:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

Comment: Você quer isso por padrão em todos? Porque considera gambiarra `["defer" => true]`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters por que gera um resultado diferente do esperado, mas irei alterar o _gambiarra_

Comment: Eu costumava a usar muito esse termo :)

Comment: Na minha opnião, você deveria criar um helper e extender HTMLHelper

Comment: Isto de estender a classe HTMLHelper vale uma ótima resposta (se adicionado com um exemplo). @WallaceMaxters

Comment: @Ricardo sobre p `['defer'=>true]` ou `[defer]` gerarem `defer="defer"` parece ser próprio do cakePHP. Talvez só estendendo a classe `Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper` mesmo. Um exemplo que demonstra ser realmente este o resultado [HtmlHelper::media](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper::media)